No option to boot into Ubuntu when I have installed both
I am currently using a dell latitude e6410 (500gb hdd storage). It is in MBR partition. I used rufus to create the bootable pendrive and installed ubuntu on my device.
In that I chose install ubuntu alongside windows and then the computer did all the things.
Later when the laptop restarted, I was directed to ubuntu only. No option came to go to windows. Even in the Boot menu, I tried to go t every possible option, but I was never directed to windows.
kindly guide me on what should I do to create this dual boot on my laptop
After this, I installed windows again with the partions.(232.3 and 232.8 and rest are for boot ig).
Thus I am currently on windows. Kindly help me to dual boot.

Windows reinstall may have deleted Ubuntu. Need more info: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

can you please specify how do I get the pastebin link and has to be done in specific(I mean what you require)
